# SQL Server: WHERE clause with null comparison

Tags: sql, null, case, where-clause

I have SP that has a parameter @NumeroTransferencia int.
I need to select rows that match that variable when it is not null.
But when it's null, I have to return the ones which have H.CodigoTransferencia = null
I tried the following but I didn't get a good result:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM RUTEO.HOJADERUTA H
WHERE 
    (H.CodigoTransferencia IS NULL OR H.CodigoTransferencia = @NumeroTransferencia)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
*
FROM RUTEO.HOJADERUTA H
WHERE 
    ((H.CodigoTransferencia IS NULL AND @NumeroTransferencia IS NULL) OR H.CodigoTransferencia = @NumeroTransferencia)
```

Comment: It works fine, it was easier than i thought... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
SELECT 
*
FROM RUTEO.HOJADERUTA H
WHERE 
    (@NumeroTransferencia IS NULL 
       AND H.CodigoTransferencia IS NULL)
 OR (@NumeroTransferencia IS NOT NULL 
      AND H.CodigoTransferencia = @NumeroTransferencia)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   RUTEO.HOJADERUTA H
WHERE  (
           @NumeroTransferencia IS NULL 
           AND H.CodigoTransferencia IS NULL
       )
       OR 
       (
           @NumeroTransferencia IS NOT NULL 
           AND H.CodigoTransferencia = @NumeroTransferencia
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
*
FROM RUTEO.HOJADERUTA H
WHERE 
    ((@NumeroTransferencia IS NULL OR H.CodigoTransferencia = @NumeroTransferencia) H.CodigoTransferencia IS NULL) 

This will only perform the search if your variable is not null otherwise it will look for H.CodigoTransferencia is equal to your variable otherwise where H.CodigoTransferencia = null
```